# how to upload 8 different images on server in iphone at a time or one after the other?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my application user should be able to upload 8 images on server?
I am able to upload one image at a time on server but how to upload 8 images on server at a time or one after the other.
please help me out:

following is my code:

```
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender
{
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [format setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%@", [format stringFromDate:now]];

    [now release];
    [format release];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/upload/uploader.php?"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     Set Header and content type of your request.
     */
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------Boundary Line---------------------------"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the request.
     */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", imageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,90)]];
    //[body appendData:[arrImages objectAtIndex:0] withFileName:@"image.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i + 1]]
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"geotag=%@&", [self _currentLocationMetadata]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // set body with request.
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    //


}
```

please help me out.

Comment: send multiple request for uploading image

Comment: can u please edit the above code so that i can get ur point......thank you

Comment: There a literally thousands of codes explaining this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe ASIHTTPRequest will make things a bit easier...

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is discontinued: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D I would recommend AFNetworking now https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudo-code

```
int i = 0
for (i<8) 
{ 
     //upload image no i here (define this before the for)
     i++;
}
```

You could either do this or use an array - whichever suits.

Comment: And this explains what? How to write a for-loop in pseudo-code?

Comment: can you please help me out to set mutiple post request for the above code........thank you.